# Reseat the container an iterator "points" to

Tags: c++, iterator, listiterator

Suppose I have a `std::list myList` and an iterator `myIt` that I am using to point to some element of the list.

Now I make a shallow copy `copiedList` of `myList` (so I can reorder it). Similarly I can make a copy `copiedIt` of `myIt`, however it still references `myList` instead of `copiedList`, meaning I cannot sensibly compare it against `copiedList.end()`, as I may have modified that list.

Is there a (standard) way to *reseat* `copiedIt` to reference `copiedList` instead? This should be semantically valid, as long as I have not made any changes to the copy.

My current solution is to use the original iterator to `std::find` the pointed-to element in the copy of the list, but while that works and causes no problems, it seems unelegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::next` and `std::distance`, like this:

```
template <class Container>
typename Container::iterator reseat(typename Container::iterator it, const Container &source, Container &target)
{
  return std::next(target.begin(), std::distance(source.begin(), it));
}
```

In prose: find the distance of `it` from the beginning of its container, and take an iterator to the same-distant element in the new container.

This could easily be generalised to allow `source` and `target` to be of different types. With slightly more work, generalisation to constant iterators is also possible.

Comment: Interested to know, presumably this has to be done prior to re-ordering `target`? Also, after re-ordering, would the reseated iterator be valid? Could it still be dereferenced? Could it be advanced to the next element in the re-ordered `target`?

Comment: @Component10 That depends on what exactly you mean with re-ordering. Each standard library container precisely spells out when its iterators become invalidated; consult [suitable reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) for details.

Answer (score 0):

How do you copy the list? If you'd iterate the first list and kept inserting the items individually, you'd get the iterator at each step: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/

This is because `list::insert` returns an iterator that points to the first of the newly inserted elements.

Comment: Well, let's assume std::copy? Or, even better, a copy constructor :)

Comment: Indeed I use a copy constructor to make the copy (note to self: check shallowness of the copy again). But if one `list::insert`ed in a loop, it would indeed be simple to split the loop around the iterator to be reseated.

Comment: @dlw "Shallow" vs. "deep" copies don't really make much sense in C++. The copy constructor simply copies the elements in the list using their copy constructors. If the elements are pointers, you only get copies of the pointers. If the elements are e.g. `std::vector<int>`, you get a new dynamic array of ints in each element. Etc.

Comment: @dlw how many iterators do you need to have updated? Angews method seems elegant for a single iterator, but std:distance's computational complexity is linear the size of the list, and if you need to have all iterators updated (because you're, for instance, creating a map between all elements of the old and new lists) this becomes an O(n^2) operation)

Comment: @Lanting Just a single iterator, and runtime complexity is no issue at all in my case, but if #iterators or list.size() became large I agree that would be worth keeping in mind.